# Согласованные и несогласованные определения

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли поставлены запятые при согласованных и несогласованных определениях?

Их применение, особенно на удаленных объектах, дает возможность использовать достаточно простую и надежную технику (,) с высокими ресурсными характеристиками, неприхотливую в работе, что уже доказано на практике.

Answer (score 1):

Указанная запятая не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Последовательность согласованных и несогласованных определений не очень понятна, поэтому желательно изменить предложение.

Предлагаемый вариант: "Их применение, особенно на удаленных объектах, дает возможность использовать достаточно простую, неприхотливую в работе, надежную технику с высокими ресурсными характеристиками,  что уже доказано на практике".

Comment: Да, так намного вернее. В исходном предложении синтаксис тяжеловат.